# Get element name by index using JavaScript and XML

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

How do I access an element from an XML document if I do not know the elements name.

```
<test_data>
    <title>test data</title>
        <test id="1">
             <test_1>
                 <example_1>Example 1 Text</example_1>
                 <example_2>Example 2 Text</example_2>
                 <example_3>Example 3 Text</example_3>
             </test_1>
        </test>
        <test id="2">
             <test_2>
                 <example_1>Example 1 Text</example_1>
                 <example_2>Example 2 Text</example_2>
                 <example_3>Example 3 Text</example_3>
             </test_2>
        </test>
        <test id="3">
             <test_3>
                 <example_1>Example 1 Text</example_1>
                 <example_2>Example 2 Text</example_2>
                 <example_3>Example 3 Text</example_3>
             </test_3>
        </test>
</test_data>
```

How can I access the elements "test_1", "test_2", "test_3". In practice I will not know the names of these elements, but I will know the index.

I cannot use getElementsByTagName, since this name is dynamic for this element. I would like to retrieve the nodes name.

I have tried the following to retrieve the element .

```
x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("test");
x[0].firstChild.nodeName;
```

This returns #text and not the node name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _“This returns #text and not the node name”_ – that _is_ the node “name”, because the first child of each of your `test` elements _is_ a text node. __White space between closing and opening tags generates text nodes.__

Answer (score 0):

### [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YMBXsG5zFuBkqGkIFFdI?p=preview)

***JS***

```
var xml = "<test_data><title>test data</title><test id='1'><test_1><example_1>Example 1 Text</example_1><example_2>Example 2 Text</example_2><example_3>Example 3 Text</example_3></test_1></test><test id='2'><test_2><example_1>Example 1 Text</example_1><example_2>Example 2 Text</example_2><example_3>Example 3 Text</example_3></test_2></test><test id='3'><test_3><example_1>Example 1 Text</example_1><example_2>Example 2 Text</example_2><example_3>Example 3 Text</example_3></test_3></test></test_data>";

if (window.DOMParser)
{
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(xml); 
}

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("test");
console.log(x);

for (i=0;i < x.length; i++){
  console.log(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeName);
}
```